# Just starting - miktex can't compile

Tags: miktex

I'm trying to get the template here to load:
http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wilson-resume-cv

I just downloaded miktex, here: http://miktex.org/download

I open cv13.tex, and tried to compile it using every typeset. None worked. Why is this happening? Do I need to install something else?

Here is the console output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(C:\Users\Daniel\Resume\cv_13.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
(C:\Users\Daniel\Resume\structure.tex
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xetexconfig\geometry.cfg"))
(C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty)
(C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\lastpage\lastpage.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested release `2014/05/01' of LaTeX,
               but only release `2011/06/27' is available.

) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
(C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hxetex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\puenc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\stringenc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
(C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty
(C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"))
(C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3unicode-data.d
ef)
(C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def)
)
(C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.
sty) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-patches.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fixltx2e.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmr.fd"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xunicode\xunicode.sty"
*** you should *not* be loading the inputenc package
*** XeTeX expects the source to be in UTF8 encoding
*** some features of other encodings may conflict, resulting in poor output.

======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
package repository: http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 208e535abbe6574359eb2ed66f1d726f
going to download 8096508 bytes
going to install 181 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/tipa.tar.lzma...
8096508 bytes, 895.44 KB/Sec
extracting files from tipa.tar.lzma...
======================================================================
(C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmss.fd"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
package repository: http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 208e535abbe6574359eb2ed66f1d726f
going to download 5957 bytes
going to install 2 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/xetex-def.tar.lzma...
5957 bytes, 118.72 KB/Sec
extracting files from xetex-def.tar.lzma...
======================================================================

(C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-def\xetex.def))))

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/property-unknown"
! 
! The key property '.choice_code:n' is unknown.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.1173  }

?
```

Edit: Below it was suggested I reinstall miktex. After doing so, I get this in my console when trying to open the file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:\Users\Daniel\Resume\cv_13.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\base\size10.clo"))
(C:\Users\Daniel\Resume\structure.tex
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/xelatex\xetexconfig\geometry.cfg"))
======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 2e1ee451b3ebfd4ef4afc81bbceafc9f
going to download 60058 bytes
going to install 7 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/fancyhdr.tar.lzma...
60058 bytes, 222.16 KB/Sec
extracting files from fancyhdr.tar.lzma...
miktex-xetex.exe: Windows API error 5: Access is denied.

miktex-xetex.exe: Data: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\doc/latex/fancyhdr
======================================================================


! LaTeX Error: File `fancyhdr.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

Tried again, got this:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:\Users\Daniel\Resume\cv_13.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
(C:\Users\Daniel\Resume\structure.tex
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xetexconfig\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty")
======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 2e1ee451b3ebfd4ef4afc81bbceafc9f
going to download 569115 bytes
going to install 8 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/lastpage.tar.lzma...
570129 bytes, 714.72 KB/Sec
visiting repository http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
repository type: remote package repository
loading lightweight database...
downloading http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
156707 bytes, 671.20 KB/Sec
lightweight database digest: 208e535abbe6574359eb2ed66f1d726f
extracting files from lastpage.tar.lzma...
======================================================================

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lastpage\lastpage.sty"

LaTeX Warning: You have requested release `2014/05/01' of LaTeX,
               but only release `2011/06/27' is available.

) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 208e535abbe6574359eb2ed66f1d726f
going to download 273472 bytes
going to install 5 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/url.tar.lzma...
273472 bytes, 702.80 KB/Sec
extracting files from url.tar.lzma...
======================================================================

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty"))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hxetex.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\puenc.def")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\stringenc.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu")))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 208e535abbe6574359eb2ed66f1d726f
going to download 7095258 bytes
going to install 43 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/l3kernel.tar.lzma...
7095258 bytes, 942.08 KB/Sec
extracting files from l3kernel.tar.lzma...
======================================================================

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3unicode-data.def")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def"))
======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 208e535abbe6574359eb2ed66f1d726f
going to download 1626854 bytes
going to install 10 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/l3packages.tar.lzma...
1626854 bytes, 779.55 KB/Sec
extracting files from l3packages.tar.lzma...
======================================================================

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-patches.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fixltx2e.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmr.fd"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xunicode\xunicode.sty"
*** you should *not* be loading the inputenc package
*** XeTeX expects the source to be in UTF8 encoding
*** some features of other encodings may conflict, resulting in poor output.

======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 208e535abbe6574359eb2ed66f1d726f
going to download 8096508 bytes
going to install 181 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/tipa.tar.lzma...
8096508 bytes, 746.06 KB/Sec
extracting files from tipa.tar.lzma...
======================================================================
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmss.fd"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
======================================================================
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 208e535abbe6574359eb2ed66f1d726f
going to download 5957 bytes
going to install 2 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/xetex-def.tar.lzma...
5957 bytes, 102.06 KB/Sec
extracting files from xetex-def.tar.lzma...
======================================================================

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-def\xetex.def"))))

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/property-unknown"
! 
! The key property '.choice_code:n' is unknown.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.1173  }

?
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. First of all, it is impossible for us to say for sure what the problem is, because you don't really tell us anything about what happens. If you installed the basic version of MikTeX, you may need to install some more packages, but you usually will be notified if that is the case.  If you get some other error, then you need to tell us what those are. Second, you will need to use either `xelatex` or `lualatex` to compile that document.

Comment: Added the console output.

Comment: I think this is a problem stemming from MikTeX having two "modes", single-user and all users. Packages installed for all users (with the Admin version of the package manager) end up in Program Files/MikTeX, while packages installed for a single user ends up in AppData/Roaming. You can see that `fontspec.sty` for example is in the former, while `expl3.sty` is in the latter. `fontspec` uses `expl3`, but sometimes the latter has a breaking update, so `fontspec` needs updating as well. A similar problem is likely the cause. (ctd.)

Comment: Try updating all the packages in MikTeX with both versions of the Update  manager, the Admin and the not-Admin one.

Comment: Where can I find the update manager? I looked it up and it says it's in the start menu but I'm using Windows 8.1 and my hacked start menu doesn't show it.

Comment: No idea, I don't use either Windows 8 or MikTeX. Can't you search in the start menu? (I think it's called Update manager, but I could be mistaken.) Alternatively, try going via the Package manager, see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55473)

Comment: I managed to update it, and now "the program can't start because QtScriptTools4.dll is missing" when I wasn't having that problem before.

Comment: When exactly do you get that error? It's likely a completely separate problem, but I cannot say why it occurs. The only (very generic) suggestion I have is to do a complete reinstallation of MikTeX. Of course, I cannot say for sure that it will help.

Answer (score 2):

The console output shows two different TDS (`texmf`) trees for the TeX files:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
...
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
```

and

```
(C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty
(C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex
...
```

Thus it seems that MiKTeX was installed as administrator for all users.
If a user only updates as user, then the files go into the `AppData` area.
The mixup of uptodate and outdated versions then causes trouble.

As Ulrike pointed out, the update should be done by the administrator and as user to keep the versions in sync. Also the LaTeX formats need to be regenerated, because it was updated quite recently.

Comment: I could only find one miktex installation to uninstall. Do you know why the second might be hidden? I did not install it twice.

Comment: Reinstalled and added a comment.

Comment: It seems like I might have permanantely screwed this over. I think I interrupted an initial installation partway through and now cannot get rid of it. It cannot be uninstalled.

Comment: One solution would be rename all directories related to both actual installations, and then make a full reinstall of Latex. Before, ensure all directories are renamed, to avoid future problems like this.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: The two locations are normal for a multiuser installation. The one is the normal install root for the admin and the other the on-the-fly installation. One only needs to run the update managers in both modes to get the updates.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Then the answer is invalid and I will delete it.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: No don't delete it. The two locations are important. But you could add a remark that this two locations are updated with two different programs.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, now I have reworded the answer.